# Maven Pom Update

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am using Spring Tool Suite (STS) for my Spring boot application development.

I am using the Spring Started Project option to select the component required for my applications. For example: if I want to develop web application, I will select the "web" check box and spring io initailzier will download all the required jars in the classpath with help of maven.

Suppose, after the project creation for WEB, If I want to add some other components in my existing web project like using Eureka, Hystrix, the required jars are not automatically setup in the classpath and couldn't use the annotation like @EnableEurekaClient as it throws error as jar is missing.

I have manually updated the pom.xml to include the Eureka starter/client/server dependency and trying to update the project (Project >> Maven >> Update Project), so that required jars will be in classpath. But it is not happening.

Any advise on it..thanks.